# How select from another table without duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have such query:

```
SELECT activity.login_time, sum(activity.sessions) FROM activity 
inner JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = activity.user_id
WHERE activity.login_time BETWEEN '2018-04-05' and '2018-04-18' 
GROUP BY activity.login_time;
```

I've got two tables (columns: activity (user_id, sessions, login_time) and payments(column: user_id). The second one has duplicate values. 
Need to select sessions for user_id from "payments" without duplicates.

My variant doesn't avoid duplicates. What should I fix in my query?

Thanks !

```
activity
user_id login_time  sessions
101 2018-04-11  4
102 2018-04-02  1
103 2018-04-15  3
104 2018-04-06  2
104 2018-04-05  6
105 2018-04-16  1
105 2018-04-04  6
105 2018-04-01  14
106 2018-04-19  5
106 2018-04-17  3
106 2018-04-16  3
106 2018-04-15  4
106 2018-04-13  2
```

Payments

```
user_id
101
103
104
106
```

output

```
login_time  sessions
2018-04-05  ?
2018-04-06  ?
2018-04-07  ?
2018-04-08  ?
2018-04-09  ?
2018-04-10  ?
2018-04-11  ?
2018-04-12  ?
2018-04-13  ?
2018-04-14  ?
2018-04-15  ?
2018-04-16  ?
2018-04-17  ?
2018-04-18  ?
```

Comment: Provide an example of actual and desired output.

Comment: Especially how to tell duplicated values apart.

Comment: @NiVeR, updated

Answer (score 0):

It seems to  me from your description you want user aggregation

```
    SELECT 
        a.user_id,
        SUM(a.sessions) as user_session
    FROM 
        activity a
    INNER JOIN 
        payments p ON p.user_id = a.user_id
    WHERE 
        a.login_time BETWEEN '2018-04-05' AND '2018-04-18' 
    GROUP BY 
        a.user_id;
```

But if you want login date with sum of each user then use subquery

```
SELECT
    a1.login_time, t1.user_session  
FROM
    activity a1 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         a.user_id,
         AVG(a.sessions) AS user_session
     FROM 
         activity a
     INNER JOIN 
         payments p ON p.user_id = a.user_id
     WHERE 
         a.login_time BETWEEN '2018-04-05' AND '2018-04-18' 
     GROUP BY 
         a.user_id) AS t1 ON a1.user_id = t1.user_id
```

Comment: hello! 
But I need two columns : date and average value

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков which date you need as user 105 login multiple time 2018-04-16,2018-04-01,2018-04-04

Comment: as I know in table 'activity' every user is only one time per day.

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков can you show your output for userid 105 then i can change my query ,cause what you said in your question that covers already in my answer

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков 2018-04-05  ? where is session column value

Comment: I cheked, but it is another view. I need only date (all unique user_id for certain day) and average quantity of sessions

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков i changed again answer

Comment: I wrote "?" because every time I got different values and don't know right values((

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков if you dont know what will be your output then no one can solve your problem

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков how you judge that your query output is wrong? what is the measurement point

Comment: I cheked the result of 05.04.2018 in Excel. So I know value of this day. I 've got table on more than 40 000 rows. 
Generally, on 05.04.2018 there 2000 users iniciated 9 000 sessions.
Amog them there were 250 users (from Payments). They initiated 1000 sessions.
I need to calculate 1000 / 250 = 4 sessions.

Answer, plz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179293/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and--).